# Move data from Sql Server 2008 to Mysql Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2008, migration

I've got legacy data in a SQL Server 2008 db.  Since rails support for SQL Server is a little complicated, I'd like to move that data to MySQL. I've installed `rails-sqlserver`, so I can access the data from the old database.

Is there a way I can read the data from the SQL Server db but then save it to the MySQL db that is running the app?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably better to leave RoR out of the migration... export the data out of SQL Server and import it into MySQL directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to move the data as a one off I'd export your data out of SQL Server as csv files providing your data isn't too complex.

I would manually create your MySQL tables so you can choose your data types as the options differ from those in SQL Server.

You could then import your csv files.